# Get value of item on OnItemClick Listview

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I try to get the value of a selected Item within a custom adapter on a listview. I try this with following code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    View curr = parent.getChildAt((int) id);
                    TextView c = (TextView)curr.findViewById(R.id.tvPopUpItem);
                    String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this,playerChanged, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

At the beginning, if I click, the values are good, but once I scrolled and I click on another Item, I get the wrong value of that clicked item... Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The parameter `v` is the current row. so use:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView c = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPopUpItem);
    String playerChanged = c.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(Settings.this,playerChanged, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

(Or you could use `getChildAt(position)` but this would be slower.)

Understand you might be able to simplify this more depending on your layout.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you have any idea why the getChildAt position didn't work? I also tried this, but this gave me errors as well..

Comment: Depending on your adapter `id` might refer to a completely different index. For example CursorAdapters return the table's primary key in `id`. `position` on the other hand should always refer to the row count.

Answer (score 0):

Just Small Change is Required

```
TextView c = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPopUpItem);
```

Since you are using custom view you need to pass the View argument in your OnItemClickListener then you need to use that value to get the Details of TextViews present in that

Comment: Next time make a comment, do not post an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i=new Intent(ListOfAstrologers.this,AstroProForUser.class);
                i.putExtra("hello",adapter.getItem(position).getUsername() );
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Here username is a string field declared in a class and you must over ride `getItem()` method in adapter class to get the details of inflated row when you click.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much experience but I think if you want to pass a variable from an OnClick (which is an anonimous class) to the outside of the onClick and to the other activity, you want to pass it via Intent intent.putExtra... (it's quite easy)
Otherwise you might end up using "public static" variable, which might be a memory leak...