# TextView.getText().toString() crashes

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter

In my application there are list view, after getting the list, when a particular item is clicked it crashes. Please help I am new in android. The code the causes error I have marked it with special character "hash"

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewClass extends ListActivity {
TextView clickedView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] adobe_products =     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));


    ListView lv = getListView();
 // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View args1, int position, long id) {
          // selected item 
         ################################################ 
         String product = ((TextView) args1).getText().toString();
         ################################################ 


          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i); 




      }
    });       
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Since I don't know the error, I guess it might be your casting to TextView.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17989959/5202007 or this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405692/5202007

Comment: If you want proper help from me or anyone here please post your log cat error message so that we can know actual reason behind the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace that line with

```
String product = ((TextView) args1.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: @SandipMondal I'm glad I could help you. Please mark my answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Sorry I am new in here and my reputation is below 15, so I am no eligible to mark your answer. Once I reach 15, I am surely going to mark your answer as accepted.Thank You Frogatto...

Comment: @SandipMondal No, please just tick my answer. (the tick below the votes buttons)

Answer (score 0):

actually you have array elements, why do you try to get value from textview.
You can get the selected item text with adobe_products[position].

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View args1, int position, long id) {
          // selected item 
         ################################################ 
         String product = adobe_products[position] ;//Editted area
         ################################################ 

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i); 
      }
    });
```